# Devirtualize shared libraries, stripping virtual-thunk operations

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to optimize the overall file size of a shared library. There are a few heavy classes inside with dozens of virtual methods and factories to create them. Unfortunately I see a huge amount of "boilerplate code" in the .text section and disassembly shows it always revolving around "virtual thunk" related operations and apparently some vtable checking. Seems to belong to different methods sometimes (maybe depending on where the first instance of a derived class is introduced) but the net result is the same, there is always a huge pile of such code lying around somewhere, even with -Os.

I need a way to minimize this, but it looks like devirtualization is not taking place, maybe this is related to the fact that it's a shared lib and the classes are exposed to symbol table. But can it be enforced somehow, without risking to break lib user's code?

Note: regular RTFM was done, -Os is applied, various code refactoring (to reduce dynamic code size) was done. Function code sizes checked multiple times with nm/objdump; symbol export control (GCC visibility) is enabled and just the minimum set of functions are marked visible. Unfortunately also classes are marked visible since library user needs to inherit from them.

Comment: You can't "devirtualise" function calls until the compiler sees the client code and sees if the run-time type is known at compile-time in the context of each call.  That happens after the shared library is built.  You're also giving us very little to go on here: "huge amount" of boilerplate - your idea of huge and problematic may not actually be unreasonable or unusual, or even problematic - you haven't explained the practical problems this is causing you.

Comment: If the devirtualization is only allowed to happen in the client code then this either means that I have lots of dead code lying around in the shared lib or that the client code won't be optimal. The code I have in mind has roughly 150 classes with virtual methods (exported) and about 1000 function signatures. The result is about 4MB of .text section code and 1.6 MB spread among other sections.

Comment: Marking leaf classes, that are not intended to be inherited from any further, as `final`, can often help the compiler to devirtualize more while optimizing. Building with LTO (Link Time Optimization) can also help. Do both for maximum win.